# Problems with remote connection to Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, remote-desktop

I've never used Windows 10 before. I tried to connect from Windows 7 to Windows 10 via Remote Desktop but it failed. Sorry, but I don't remember the error message. After that I read somewhere in the internet that I have to create an `.rdp` file with the contents:

```
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
```

and to open this file in the connection dialog before I connect. I did it and I could connect to Windows 10. I could see the remote screen with my user name and password prompt. But after I typed the password the error appeared:

```
The user name or password is incorrect
```

But they are both correct because I use the notebook without Remote Desktop and can login. I also read somewhere in the internet that Windows 10 provides 2 sign-in options: PIN and password. I know that I use PIN. Can this be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the user you're trying to log in remotely has access and correct security permissions to log in and make sure that Remote Desktop is enabled in windows 10

Comment: The user is Administrator. Remote Desktop is enabled.

Comment: Then make sure when using credentials to use the user administrator without the domain if you're on a domain

Comment: I have tried the both: AzureAD\User and User with the same result

Comment: I need exact error please

Comment: The result in both cases was: The user name or password is incorrect

Comment: is the keyboards on both end have same input language ?